# Taxonomy works in local XAMPP but doesn't work live

Tags: taxonomy, xampp

this project was done on a Mac, it worked very well in the Mac's local XAMPP and online as well. Now I try to transfer it to my laptop(windows), the taxonomy doesn't work in the laptop's local XAMPP, the rest part of the website are good. I copy and paste everything(localhost files and sql) from the original one.

Comment: Have you got 404 error for Taxonomy?

Comment: Hi, yes, I have 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings** » **Permalinks**, and simply click on the **Save Changes** button.

If Still, you face the same issue then,  check your .htaccess file or IIS config file.

Comment: Hi Arvind,I've tried the permalinlinks thing already, didn't work. And I think this shouldn't be the configuration issue, because I migrated 4 projects yesterday, only this one got the taxonomy issue. Thanks anyway.